# How to move form elements to the centre?

Tags: html, css

How do I move a contact form that is within the red background you see in the image be in the centre?

[image]

```
<form id="wpforms-form-680" class="wpforms-validate wpforms-form" data-formid="680" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/staging/2490/" data-token="22197d396681c8092b8e8acb3cf9b0e5" novalidate="novalidate">
   <noscript class="wpforms-error-noscript">Please enable JavaScript in your browser to complete this form.</noscript>
   <div class="wpforms-field-container">
      <div id="wpforms-680-field_0-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-name contact-form-labels" data-field-id="0"><label class="wpforms-field-label" for="wpforms-680-field_0">Name <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span></label><input type="text" id="wpforms-680-field_0" class="wpforms-field-medium wpforms-field-required" name="wpforms[fields][0]" required=""></div>
      <div id="wpforms-680-field_1-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-email" data-field-id="1"><label class="wpforms-field-label" for="wpforms-680-field_1">Email <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span></label><input type="email" id="wpforms-680-field_1" class="wpforms-field-medium wpforms-field-required" name="wpforms[fields][1]" required=""></div>
      <div id="wpforms-680-field_2-container" class="wpforms-field wpforms-field-textarea" data-field-id="2">
         <label class="wpforms-field-label" for="wpforms-680-field_2">Project Details <span class="wpforms-required-label">*</span></label>
         <textarea id="wpforms-680-field_2" class="wpforms-field-medium wpforms-field-required wpforms-limit-characters-enabled" data-form-id="680" data-field-id="2" data-text-limit="10000" name="wpforms[fields][2]" placeholder="Please include your contact number if you would like a call back" maxlength="10000" required=""></textarea>
         <div class="wpforms-field-limit-text" id="wpforms-field-limit-text-680-2">0 of 10000 max characters.</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="wpforms-submit-container"><input type="hidden" name="wpforms[id]" value="680"><input type="hidden" name="wpforms[author]" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="wpforms[post_id]" value="2"><button type="submit" name="wpforms[submit]" class="wpforms-submit contact-form-button" id="wpforms-submit-680" value="wpforms-submit" aria-live="assertive" data-alt-text="Sending..." data-submit-text="Send">Send</button></div>
</form>


div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input.wpforms-field-medium,
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form .wpforms-field-row.wpforms-field-medium {
    max-width: 100%;
}

div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=email], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=text], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form textarea{
    width:70%;
}
```

When I add margin auto to the above css I have posted, it does move the text input and test area to the centre, but the labels don't move. Been trying to figure out how to move it as when I tried to add margin: auto for .wpforms-field-label, it doesn't move it.

The full css from what I have ripped out from doing an inspect:

```
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form .wpforms-field-label {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: none;
    line-height: 1.3;
    margin: 0 0 4px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form label, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form select, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form button, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form textarea {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: none;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.wpforms-container-full, div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form * {
    background: none;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    float: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    height: auto;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    list-style: none;
    outline: none;
    position: static;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    width: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -ms-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.contact-form label {
    margin-bottom: .25em;
    float: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just add `text-align:center;` to your project.

```
form#wpforms-form-680 {
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use flexbox to center your form.

```
form#wpforms-form-680{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I add margin auto to the above css I have posted, it does move the text input and test area to the centre, but the labels don't move.

That certainly is because, with the below rule, the inputs and textarea width are set to 70%... And the labels still have a width of 100%.

```
div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=email], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form input[type=text], div.wpforms-container-full .wpforms-form textarea{
    width:70%;
}
```

I would apply the `width: 70%` and `margin: 0 auto;` on the `<form>` instead, so everything inside would move to the center while being left aligned. It is more simple and will be easier to adjust for mobile with an `@media` rule.